# Linear model diagnostics: smoothing line obtained in ggplot2 is different from the one obtained with base plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, model, diagnostics

I am trying to reproduce the diagnostics plots for a linear regression model using ggplot2. The smoothing line that I get is different from the one obtained using base plots or ggplot2::autoplot.

```
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
model <- lm(wt.loss ~ meal.cal, data=lung)
## Fitted vs. residuals using base plot:
plot(model, which=1)
## Fitted vs. residuals using ggplot
model.frame <- fortify(model)
ggplot(model.frame, aes(.fitted, .resid)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="loess", se=FALSE)
```

The smoothing line is different, the influence of the the first few points is much larger using the loess method provided by ggplot. My question is: how can I reproduce the smoothing line obtained with plot() using ggplot2?

Comment: Of course it's different - your "base" model is a linear model with `wt.loss ~ meal.cal` whereas the regression line in your ggplot2 call is a LOESS. Oranges and apples. Try replacing `"loess"` with `"lm"`.

Comment: But I don't need a regression line. If you look at the graph obtained with the base plot command, it contains a smoothed line, not a linear regression line. My point is: why is the smoothed line obtained with base plot is not equal to the one obtained with geom_smooth? My guess is that base::plot does not use the LOESS algorithm, but I have no clue about which. Please re-consider your decision to downvote.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question, sorry. I think you should check the span value, which controls how smooth/jagged the regression line is.

Comment: Looking at the source code, `plot.lm` ([here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/plot.lm.R#L134)) uses `panel` function, which is, by default [`panel.smooth`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/master/src/library/graphics/R/coplot.R#L38). Notice that this function uses `lowess`, and not `loess`, to plot smoothed residuals.

Comment: I think you are right and that the differences between the two graphs are due to the different algorithm used. I am trying to figure out how to have ggplot use lowess instead of loess: any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry to not have followed up on this. A slight cold has shaved a few hours a night off and was unable to revisit this. I have never tried using lowess directly in geom_smooth, but even if it wouldn't work for some reason, you can always calculate it outside and use e.g. `geom_path` or `geom_line` to create this smoother.

Comment: Thanks! geom_smooth does not like "lowess", but using stats::lowess to calculate the coordinates and then geom_line to plot them does the trick! Thank you, if you post an answer I will accept it. Since my original question was not so obvious as you thought at first, please consider to undo the downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the `lowess`, which is used to plot the red line in the original diagnostic plot, using samename base function.

```
smoothed <- as.data.frame(with(model.frame, lowess(x = .fitted, y = .resid)))

ggplot(model.frame, aes(.fitted, .resid)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(shape = 1, size = 2) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dotted", col = "grey") +
  geom_path(data = smoothed, aes(x = x, y = y), col = "red")
```

[image]

And the original:

[image]